# Why does Eileen have a tail?

Tags: regular-show

I've started watching The Regular show, and Eileen who seems to be human, has a tail.

The show has a few non humans, and a few humans. But I've not seen any hybrids.

**What is Eileen, and why does she have a tail?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Regular_Show_characters) for the show lists her character as a **mole**, not a human.

> **Eileen Lynn Roberts** (voiced by Minty Lewis, a writer/storyboard artist
>   for the series) **is a shy and timid mole** who works at a local coffee
>   shop, previously alongside Margaret.

And from [this interview](http://pscomics.com/) with the voice actor

> *Second: a new episode of Regular Show written and boarded by Kat
>   Morris and myself is now available on youtube (for a limited time?).
>   There’s some stuff I really like in this one, and **everyone’s favorite
>   mole Eileen (voiced by me) is featured quite prominently.** So please do
>   me a favor and watch “Do Me a Solid.”*